# Get Lat and Log of actual location without google maps

Tags: java, android, location

I tried network and GPs provider based codes to get perfect location where the device is, but always there is inaccuracy in lat and lon. I used http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html to get values and got lat as 19.10295898 and lon as 72.8866532. Where as by google maps it is lat,lon are 19.103114,72.8867978. There is difference. Can we actually match it somehow. Code used is below:

```
package jss.fusedlocation;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.nearby.messages.Distance;

/**
 * Created by DELL WORLD on 1/23/2017.
 */

public class ShowLocationActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {
    private TextView latituteField;
    private TextView longitudeField;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private String provider;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        latituteField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
        longitudeField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView04);

        // Get the location manager
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        // Define the criteria how to select the locatioin provider -> use
        // default
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        location.setAccuracy(1);

        // Initialize the location fields
        if (location != null) {
            System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
            onLocationChanged(location);
        } else {
            latituteField.setText("Location not available");
            longitudeField.setText("Location not available");
        }
    }

    /* Request updates at startup */
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1, 1, this);
    }

    /* Remove the locationlistener updates when Activity is paused */
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        double lat = (double) (location.getLatitude());
        double lng = (double) (location.getLongitude());
        latituteField.setText(String.valueOf(lat));
        longitudeField.setText(String.valueOf(lng));
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Enabled new provider " + provider,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Disabled provider " + provider,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried network and GPs provider based codes to get perfect location where the device is

In general, it is not possible "to get perfect location where the device is", by any means. There are many variables involved in obtaining the location, and not all of those variables will be in your favor at all times.

> Can we actually match it somehow

As far as we know, Google Maps uses the Play Services SDK's [fused location provider](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi).